# PHP x64 still returns wrong filesize

Tags: php, size, filesize

I am trying to get the file size of files >2GB, but PHP seams to have problems regardless of 64 or 32 bit versions. On the PHP 64bit version running on a 64bit processor on a 64 bit OS, it still returns the wrong file size using filesize() function. Before I have encountered that it returns a negative number, or nothing at all... the number is changing if the file size is changing, but is not accurate on files > 2gb... I could understand a number less than actual size, zero or even negative numbers if php is using 32bit integers, but as I read, php 64bit is supposed to support file sizes > 2gb...

I have also tried using fseek to end and ftell like:

```
$a = fopen("c:\big.txt", 'r');
fseek($a,0,SEEK_END);
$fs = ftell($a);
fclose($a);
echo $fs;
```

But that just gives 0...

Comment: This page may have better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501451/php-x86-how-to-get-filesize-of-2gb-file-without-external-program

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `filesize` function?

```
echo filesize('c:\big.txt');
```

This function may not work properly on 32-bit systems, but should give you the correct size on a 64-bit system:

> Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.

Comment: I think the OP has already tried that. And the notes in the documentation for that function say "some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB."

Comment: You mention that the filesize is changing. Is another process appending to the file? If so try doing `clearstatcache()` before the call to `filesize`: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Answer (score 0):

The manual actually says "This may be broken on your platform. Oh, too bad."

This comment may help: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#113457 . It something similar to what you tried, but it seems to assume SEEK_END doesn't work either.

```
function RealFileSize($fp)
{
    $pos = 0;
    $size = 1073741824;
    fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while ($size > 1)
    {
        fseek($fp, $size, SEEK_CUR);

        if (fgetc($fp) === false)
        {
            fseek($fp, -$size, SEEK_CUR);
            $size = (int)($size / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            fseek($fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            $pos += $size;
        }
    }

    while (fgetc($fp) !== false)  $pos++;

    return $pos;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I didn't try this.*

Comment: Looks interesting, however, when I tried it, it looped until it was stopped by the 30 second limit.. I am assuming that even if it worked, it is taking too long to be acceptable in use... I need a function that will be somewhat efficient as it will be handeling a lot of files...

Comment: The only "kind of" reliable way I can think of is to create a third party console application that accepts a file name as argument and then have it pass trough the PHP script, but even if i do so, will php be able to handle long integers? like a simple if($size >=9000000000) ?  besides, now the script would be locked to one platform, and thats not even considering the performance penalty of using a third party pass trhough...