# Alternative to fseek() in PHP for files larger than 2-4GB on a 32-bit system

Tags: php, linux, 32-bit, seek, fseek

I need to seek around in large files of between 30GB-500GB. Unfortunately I need to do this on a 32-bit system.

I've just crashed into PHP's 2GB limit with `fseek()`, in a way I've not seen documented online.

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(fseek(fopen("/dev/sda", "r"), 0, SEEK_END));'
int(-1)
```

So the syscall is returning `-1`. I wonder why:

```
$ strace php -r 'var_dump(fseek(fopen("/dev/sda", "r"), 0, SEEK_END));'
...
lstat64("/dev/sda", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(8, 0), ...}) = 0
lstat64("/dev", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=5460, ...}) = 0
open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY)              = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(8, 0), ...}) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_END)                   = -1 EOVERFLOW (Value too large for defined data type)
```

This is happening on a file only 60GB in size.

So I can't even seek to the end - `lseek()` is apparently incapable of representing the file pointer back to PHP.

On a separate note, repeatedly seeking forward with SEEK_CUR seems to get stuck at 4GB - I can't move the file pointer past that point. I need to seek to the end of 500GB files.

What are my alternatives? My current plans are to use `dd` (this is on Linux), and the tool I'm writing might as well be a shell script at this point...

Comment: Is this any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501451/php-x86-how-to-get-filesize-of-2-gb-file-without-external-program

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Unfortunately not - that project only uses a bunch of different techniques to get **only** the file *size* - for example it can use libcurl to do a header-only request for the `file://` path and then extract the file size from the `Content-Length` field (yeah). Pretty ingenious if you ask me; I'm just disappointed that PHP was so badly mis-designed back in the day when there was only one chance to get this right. Ah well.

Comment: I think I'm going to end up using a shell script for this, because I was already going to shell out to the `xz` utility (the only XZ library for PHP is 4 years old, unmaintained, segfaults far too easily for my liking, offers no low-level control, and only works for files) to do stream compression. For anyone else needing to solve this - libcurl ***might*** work if you do a `file://` request and set the Range header. Untested, tell me if it works! (Just thought of this while typing the above comment).