# Read file size of videos greater than 10Gb in PHP

Tags: php, filesize

I'm using PHP on XAMPP with Windows 10:

I have a local page in which I need to read the file size of all videos in a folder.

Until now I used the `filesize()` function:

```
filesize("_video_/".$file)
```

For videos larger than 2Gb, this function, returns a negative value so I found a solution online where you can just add (4*1024*1024*1024)to the result and everything worked well.

Now I've a video larger than 10Gb and the result isn't right. It is a positive number but it's a lot smaller than the real one.

Are there ways to do that?

Comment: Not used it myself, but a colleague showed me this in the past and might be what you need: https://gist.github.com/mattvot/877c518f5545b2844433 ... I don't think i twas tested with 10gb plus files by my colleague though

Comment: Maybe overkill for what you're doing but this looks relevant: https://github.com/jkuchar/BigFileTools

Comment: Sounds like you're on a 32-bit operating system or using a 32-bit build of PHP. Can you check using `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Dammeul & Alexander I'm gonna try your suggestions, thank you!

@halfer yes it's a 32bit build of php but the system is 64 bit.Is it possible to upgrade it without reinstalling xampp? Using php 64 bit will solve the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I believe that upgrading to 64-bit PHP would solve it. Try this on a non-live server first, of course.

Comment: I should think, in relation to your reinstall question, that it would be a fresh install. 64-bit PHP will be completely different binaries (but you can use the same `php.ini`).

Comment: (Incidentally, if you are having troubles with getting your code to work on particular environments, take a look at Docker on Linux. Your app becomes indivisible from the environment you're running in, meaning there's much less chance for a surprise when you move to staging/live.)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't exist a 64bit version of xampp for windows :(

Comment: That appears to be true. You can just install the things separately, then - [PHP is here](https://windows.php.net/download/) and has two 64-bit releases for PHP 7.2.

Comment: I tried to download it and link it to xampp in httpd.conf but apache doesn't start and I can't find a guide about how to link another installation of php to xampp.

Comment: Ok I solved it using Alessandro Marinuzzi's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501451/php-x86-how-to-get-filesize-of-2-gb-file-without-external-program?noredirect=1&lq=1

For now it seems to work.